# What is the case of using Buffer.allocUnsafe() and Buffer.alloc()?

Tags: node.js

I am confused about using `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` and `Buffer.alloc()` , I know that `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` creates a buffer with pre-filled data or old buffers, but why do i need such thing if `Buffer.alloc()` creates a buffer with zero filled data

Comment: I guess flushing the buffer takes time. If you need performance and you know you will completly fill the buffer anyway, there would be no need to flush it first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Node.js `Buffer` is an abstraction over RAM, therefore if you allocate it in an unsafe way, there is a high risk of having even some source code in the buffer instance. Try running `console.log(Buffer.allocUnsafe(10000).toString('utf-8'))` and I guarantee that you will see some code in your stdout.

Allocation is a synchronous operation and we know that single threaded Node.js doesn't really feel good about synchronous stuff. Unsafe allocation is much faster than safe, because the buffer santarization step takes time. Safe allocation is, well, safe, but there is a performance trade off.

I'd suggest sticking to safe allocation first and if you end up with low performance, you can think of ways to implement unsafe allocation, without exposing private stuff. Just keep in mind that `allocUnsafe` method has the word `unsafe` for a reason. E.g, if you are going to pass some compliance certification like PCI DSS, I'm pretty sure QSA will notice that and will have a lot of questions.

Comment: I want to add that if you are 100% sure you are overwriting all data it is perfectly safe to use unsafeAlloc. E.g a copy operation. `const bufferCopy = Buffer.allocUnsafe(oldBuffer.length); oldBuffer.copy(bufferCopy);` Which is one of the perfect use cases for `allocUnsafe`.

Comment: Yep the Buffer API runs outside the V8 heap meaning it directly allocates RAM memory (which may be  not empty if we use unsafe methods)

Answer (score 2):

> Buffer.alloc(size, fill, encoding) -> returns a new initialized Buffer
> of the specified size. This method is slower than Buffer.allocUnsafe(size) but guarantees that newly created Buffer instances never contain old data that is potentially sensitive.
>
> Buffer.allocUnsafe(size) -> the Buffer is uninitialized, the allocated
> segment of memory might contain old data that is potentially
> sensitive. Using a Buffer created by Buffer.allocUnsafe() without completely overwriting the memory can allow this old data to be leaked when the Buffer memory is read.

Note: While there are clear performance advantages to using Buffer.allocUnsafe(), extra care must be taken in order to avoid introducing security vulnerabilities into an application